# WPF System.Private.CoreLib.dll tries to load symbols from non-existent drive

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, .net-6.0

Since today Visual Studio 2022 CE tries to load symbols for System.Private.CoreLib.dll which should be on drive "D:". The problem is drive "D:" does not exist. At least not permanently.

It is a .net6 WPF application.

I am still quite new to Visual Studio and C# and just don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you install a framework or sdk to a D: drive ?

Comment: What did you do when you DID have a D: drive?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andy. That's the problem. I didn't really do anything consciously. The device I have mounted as drive D is a media server and is only used for that. According to Microsoft Docs, the path to the symbol files should be stored in VS under 'Tools > Options > Debugging > Symbols', but this was not the case. Finally I reset VS to factory settings and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting VS to factory settings solved the problem.

Comment: Hi rafa, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)